# Android BluetoothSocket will not connect: read failed, socket might closed or timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth

Trying to handle connecting to a bluetooth device for the first time, following the instructions at [Android Dev: Connect Bluetooth devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices).

Right now I'm just trying to get anything working at all, so I'm working in a test project with a very specific bluetooth device which is an Allflex LPR RFID Reader "LPR_64980".

I'm able to start discovery and find the LPR RFID reader and get it's `BluetoothDevice` object. I store that in `this.rfidreader` and create and start a ConnectThread (Google's code):

```
public void tappedConnectLPR() {
        new ConnectThread(rfidreader).start();
}
```

I'm able to create the `BluetoothSocket`, but when I call `mmSocket.connect()`, it blocks (as expected) for about 20 seconds and throws an `IOException`: `exception: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`. There is also one more line shown in the logcat:

```
13:38:12.789  D  close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@7eb866e, channel: -1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@951f10f, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@ff0659c, mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@af8fba5
                 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@f4d9b7a fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@3c68f2b, mSocketState: INIT
```

My iPhone is able to fully connect to this device without a problem, so I know that this device will work. And I've made sure to disconnect the iPhone and have the iPhone forget the device so that it won't try to interfere when my Android phone is trying to connect.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private static final UUID bluetoothServiceUUID = UUID.fromString("5cb6b8e2-b944-44b3-b806-a92d4587123c");

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
        // because mmSocket is final.
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        try {
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice.
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used in the server code.
            Log.d("MA", "about to create rfcomm socket...");
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(bluetoothServiceUUID);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MA", "Socket's create() method failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        Log.d("MA", "got rfcomm socket...");
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
        Log.d("MA", "stopping discovery, just in case");
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            Log.d("MA", "trying to connect");
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.d("MA", "connected?");

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
            Log.d("MA", "exception: "+connectException.getMessage());

            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e("MA", "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }

        // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
        // the connection in a separate thread.
        manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MA", "Could not close the client socket", e);
        }
    }
}
```